# Mathematica introduces unneccessary/wrong square root of complex number

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex

I'm trying to use Mathematica to get the eigenvalues of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon & v + ue^{ika} \\ v + u e^{-ika} & \epsilon \end{bmatrix}

Executing the following

```
Eigenvalues[{{\[Epsilon], v + u*Exp[I*k*a]}, {v + u*Exp[(-I)*k*a], \[Epsilon]}}]
```

gives as result:

\begin{equation} e^{-i a k} \left(\epsilon  e^{i a k} \pm \sqrt{u^2 e^{2 i a k}+u v e^{i a k}+u v e^{3 i a k}+v^2 e^{2 i a k}}\right) \end{equation}

and after `FullSimplify` with no further assumptions:

\begin{equation} \epsilon \pm e^{-i a k} \sqrt{e^{2 i a k} \left(2 u v \cos (a k)+u^2+v^2\right)} \end{equation}

As far as I can tell Mathematica cannot simplify further due to the square root of a complex number and the associated branch cut. However as is very quick and easy to check the eigenvalues should be given by

\begin{equation} \epsilon \pm \sqrt{\left(2 u v \cos (a k)+u^2+v^2\right)} \end{equation}

This can also be verified by asking Mathematica to diagonalise the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} a + ib & c + id \\ e + if & a + ib \end{bmatrix}

(I used explicitly complex entries of the matrix to make sure it doesn't accidentally assume they are real). The output of this are the eigenvalues:

\begin{equation} a+i b \pm \sqrt{c e+i c f+i d e-d f} \end{equation}

The first matrix is simply a special case of the second matrix, with the complex numbers expressed using exponentials and as such the results should be exactly the same. Why does Mathematica seem to treat these cases differently and introduce an extra square root of a complex number in the first case leading to an incorrect expression due to an additional branch cut.

Comment: Take the factor inside the `Sqrt`, i.e., `expr /. a_*Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[a^2*x]`

Comment: This is largely due to an internal optimization that, for this example, is unhelpful. The idea is to pull out any common divisor from the matrix before going into further processing. `PolynomialGCD` thinks the common divisor in this case is`E^(-I a k)` rather than 1.

Comment: Try this  `Eigenvalues[ ... ] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand`